# Wordpress <ul> class reference issue

Tags: wordpress, list, navigation

I can't seem to figure out how to call a class for the  tag in my navigation menu... I'm using the wp_nav_array reference but it doesn't seem to work. Here is the mark up:

HTML

```
<div class="navigation_bar">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="active"><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Header.php File

```
            <?php wp_nav_menu(array( 'menu_class' => 'navigation_bar navigation', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'theme_location'  => 'header-menu') ); ?>
```

How it displays in browsers

```
<div class="navigation_bar">
    <ul>
       <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=6">Home</a></li>
       <li class="page_item page-item-12 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=12">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How I **NEED** it to display in browsers

```
<div class="navigation_bar">
    <ul class="navigation">
       <li class="page_item page-item-6"><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=6">Home</a></li>
       <li class="page_item page-item-12 current_page_item"><a href="http://localhost/?page_id=12">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I appreciate all suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu_class' => 'navigation_bar', 'container_class' => 'navigation', 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'theme_location' => 'header-menu') ); ?>
```

More on calling [WP Nav Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)

**UPDATE:**

After taking a closer look, I realized that there is no 'sort_column' option available for wp_nav_menu. Call it like so:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('menu_class' => 'navigation_bar', 'container_class' => 'navigation', 'theme_location' => 'header-menu') ); ?>
```

Comment: I tried that before as well, it did nothing to it though... Here is my function in the functions.php file. `function register_my_menus() {
  register_nav_menus(
    array( 'header-menu' => __( 'Main Navigation' ) )
  );
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );
`

Comment: Please review the update. If you look at the documentation provided in the original answer, you'll find that there is no 'sort_column' parameter available for that particular function, which is probably messing with everything.

Comment: Still no luck. I just removed the old line and entered that code and still nothing happened... I'm really confused as to why its doing this...

Comment: Edit: I went and just messed around with the CSS and found that doing that was the easiest solution. It's all fixed. Thanks for everything.